# Get total and free disk space using Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, prometheus

I try to get Total and Free disk space on my Kubernetes VM so I can display % of taken space on it. I tried various metrics that included "filesystem" in name but none of these displayed correct total disk size. Which one should be used to do so?

Here is a list of metrics I tried

```
node_filesystem_size_bytes
node_filesystem_avail_bytes
node:node_filesystem_usage:
node:node_filesystem_avail:
node_filesystem_files
node_filesystem_files_free
node_filesystem_free_bytes
node_filesystem_readonly
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

According to my Grafana dashboard, the following metrics work nicely for alerting for available space,

`100 - ((node_filesystem_avail_bytes{mountpoint="/",fstype!="rootfs"} * 100) /            node_filesystem_size_bytes{mountpoint="/",fstype!="rootfs"})`

The formula gives out the percentage of available space on the pointed disk. Make sure you include the mountpoint and fstype within the metrics.

Comment: Using your method I get incorrect total disk size - I know I have 40Gb total but displayed is 42Gb. Can you explain why it might be like that? I just copy-pasted `node_filesystem_size_bytes{mountpoint="/",fstype!="rootfs"}`

Comment: Are you converting by power of 10? From byte to kb for example, division by 1024 is expected, which makes a difference when going from bytes to Gb.

Comment: I specified `node_filesystem_size_bytes{mountpoint="/",fstype!="rootfs"}` query with bytes unit

Comment: So, for example what is the output?

Comment: `42.0 GB` for query given above. For following query `node_filesystem_size_bytes{mountpoint="/",fstype!="rootfs"}*(1e+9)` with unit hardset to Gb it displays `42 GB`

Comment: In bytes, that should be a large number. What is the output it displays?

Comment: With `node_filesystem_size_bytes{mountpoint="/",fstype!="rootfs"}` and no unit type set - `42004086784` - here ofc displays bytes with no calculations; bytes - `42.0 GB`; Gb - `42 GB`

Comment: Ok, let’s divide the 42 trillion number with 1024 to arrive at KB and then again division by 1024 for Mb. At this point I calculate 40058 mb. Now divide by 1024 and it is ~39 GB. You can trust the output of this metrics and converting it to a percentage is generally useful.

Comment: Thank you for clear noobish explanation. I'll give it a day or two and will accept your answer as it's fairly close to fully correct answer (that extra 2Gb or 1Gb less might be harmful in a long run). Are you able to explain why there is a difference between calculating it by myself and calculating it automatically by Grafana/Prometheus with unit types specified?

Comment: Where do you see an output as GB? In my Prometheus console, only results in bytes units are displayed.

Comment: In Grafana Dashboard I added Singlestat panel. Selected Prometheus as Data Source that I created previously and when I select Unit in Options I get a result with calculated units. In Prometheus console I also see output only in bytes

Comment: My bad, my explanation lacked diff between GB and GiB, and my notation was wrong. So under Grafana - Unit - Disk(Metrics) outputs Gigabytes whereas Unit - Disk(IEC) outputs Gibibytes, what I was calculating. Df command outputs in GiB. units.

Comment: @AYA Thanks for the answer! If I understand correctly you filtered to mountpoint / (the root of the filesystem) because that's where the harddisk will be mounted on. That way you avoid picking up mountpoints like /run, which is just a tmpfs (memory-backed filesystem). You make sure the fstype is not rootfs as that is also a memory-backed filesystem. Is that correct? It would probably be good to add a explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 13):

FS utilization can be calculated as

```
100 - (100 * ((node_filesystem_avail_bytes{mountpoint="/",fstype!="rootfs"} )  / (node_filesystem_size_bytes{mountpoint="/",fstype!="rootfs"}) ))
```

Comment: This looks like an exact copy of @AYA answer above.

Answer (score -1):

According [kubernetes-mixin](https://github.com/kubernetes-monitoring/kubernetes-mixin) you can use [node:node_filesystem_usage](https://github.com/kubernetes-monitoring/kubernetes-mixin/blob/master/rules/rules.libsonnet#L382), but if this metrics won't show your correct vales please ensure that `device` is set correctly.

I highly recommend using Prometheus `Graph` or Graphana `Explore` tab to check all available metrics.

Comment: How can I make sure device is set correctly? Using Panel "Graph" and calling `node:node_filesystem_usage` I receive only 1 line with tiny values. I see device but I dunno how I can verify if it's correct or eighter how to change it if it's wrong

Comment: As you can see in [node:node_filesystem_usage](https://github.com/kubernetes-monitoring/kubernetes-mixin/blob/master/rules/rules.libsonnet#L382) deffinition it takes `node_filesystem_avail_bytes` and `node_filesystem_size_bytes`, so first check those metrics.